# How to pipe a stream to another notebook?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, streams

Can I pipe an `OutputStream` object created by `OpenWrite` (or similar) to a notebook instead of a file? I am aware that I can use `NotebookWrite`, but I want to have all the `Write` statements in my code to be redirected to file/notebook by simply switching a variable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am not sure that this is possible.  The `$Output` and `$Messages` variables hold the output stream to where the standard output (and the message output) from the kernel goes.  If you check these, you'll see that they're simply set to `stdout`.

If you remove `ReadProtected` from `NotebookWrite`, you'll see that it is passing data to the front end instead of writing to an output stream.

All this suggest that it's not possible to redirect an output stream to an arbitrary notebook.

---

Instead of using output streams to switch the output "device", I'd suggest switching the output function.  You could have a function `write` which can be set to `write = Write[outputChannel, #]&` or to `write = NotebookWrite[nb, #]&`.

If you already have a lot of code using `Write` then it would be inconvenient to rewrite it to use an alternative write function.  But you can temporarily redefine `Write` using a block:

```
Block[{ Write = NotebookWrite[nb, #2]& },

 .... (* code called here *)

]
```

If you need to temporarily redefine `Write` with something that itself uses `Write`, then you can use the [trick described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/695132) to "wrap" it with extra code.

---

Note: As @Heike said below, `NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[#2]], "Output"]] &` is better for writing into notebooks than the simple `NotebookWrite[nb, #2]&` I used above.

Comment: +1 for using block, although you would probably need to define `Write = NotebookWrite[#1, Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[#2]], "Output"]] &` or something to make it work.

Comment: I was afraid of this. Isn't the purpose of streaming/piping to provide means of saving data by easy redirection? Considering, that [this bug](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/bd9b6dfd356fa886/dfe3e85496a3d2b4?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=Istv%C3%A1n+Zachar#dfe3e85496a3d2b4) is still not resolved, piping is really not that easy in _Mathematica_...

Comment: @Istvan I agree with Szabolcs. Streams are a pretty low-level I/O tool, suitable also for reading/writing of unstructured data (e.g., not even representing valid Mathematica expressions). Notebooks are structured documents, and writing to them assumes, to my mind,  higher-level I/O abstraction. If you feel a need to redirect there, it might mean that your current design is too low-level (regarding logging or whatever purpose it is you use `Write` for), so you will be better off by redesigning this part of your code to use higher-level constructs.

Comment: @IstvánZachar, I did not realize that that bug was that old.

Comment: @István "bump" doesn't really work on a newsgroup as the old message may very well be lost in most newsreaders.  Funny the moderator even let it through ..

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: I thought that using streams is much fastar to save data than using other functions - at least for files. Now for notebooks, I understand that this might not be the case.

Comment: @Istvan The speed should never be the primary concern at the start, at least unless you know in advance that speed is central to the application. In Mathematica, we perhaps need to think of it more than in some other languages (e.g. Python), but the principle still holds. With my demonstrated attachement to microbenchmarks, I may sound hypocritical here, but I actually *do* follow this principle for whatever code I have to write. Microbenchmarking is useful to see how fast you *can* be within the language, if you absolutely have to (i.e. fore real bottlenecks).

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes, I had plenty of time to figure that out and draw the consequences :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way that allows you to actually redirect output to a notebook by using the newish [`DefineStreamOutputMethod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefineOutputStreamMethod.html) function (which dates to 9.0). It's a bit hacky by its very nature, and the version I have here creates a **new** notebook for output, but I think it's a reasonable place to start. There's certainly room for refinement!

```
DefineOutputStreamMethod["Notebook",
 {
  "ConstructorFunction" ->
   Function[{name, isAppend, caller, opts},
    With[{state = Unique["NotebookOutputStream"]},
     state["notebook"] =
      CreateNotebook[FilterRules[opts, Options[Notebook]]];
     {True, state}]],

  "CloseFunction" -> Function[state, ClearAll[state]],

  "WriteFunction" -> Function[{state, bytes},
    (* Since we're writing to a cell, we don't want that trailing newline. *)
    With[{out = bytes /. {most___, 10} :> FromCharacterCode[{most}]},
     With[{nb = state["notebook"]},
      If[NotebookInformation@nb === $Failed || out === "",
       {0, state},
       NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[out, "Output"], After];
       {Length@bytes, state}]]]]
  }];
```

Try it out like this:

```
With[{stream = OpenWrite[Method -> "Notebook"]},
 Block[{$Output = stream},
  Do[Print[i], {i, 10}];
  Close[stream]]]
```