# How do I direct output to a specific notebook or cell?

Tags: notebooks, streams

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pipe a stream to another notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1041/how-to-pipe-a-stream-to-another-notebook)

Is there any way to create a stream so that all output to the stream (from `Write` or something similar) goes to a specific notebook, or to a specific cell?

I think `CellPrint` almost does what I want, but I would need to manipulate the selection in order to have the newly generated cell end up where I want it, and more annoyingly, I can no longer make use of the functionality by using a stream as an argument.

**EDIT** to add:

As an example of what I'm trying to do, say I have a function like this:

```
foo[] := Print["I am Spartacus!"];
```

What I want is some function, `whatever`, which will allow me to do this:

```
Block[{$Output = whatever[]},
 foo[]];
```

and have "I am Spartacus!" appear in another notebook, instead of in a cell underneath the cell I just evaluated. I don't want to have to change the definition of `foo`, because it's really a long function with a lot of `Print` statements used for logging purposes.